How to use "pmd check" to scan for language php?
im sorry its very very newbie question. But I dont know where to find pmd rules for php.
I am properly able to run
pmd check -R rulesets/java/quickstart.xml -f text --dir MyProject

But not for php
pmd check -R rulesets/php/quickstart.xml -f text --dir MyProjectPhp

I understand by reading the jar file that ruleset/java is an Internal ruleset, but where is the php ruleset, it does exist open source? Is it the correct usage syntax, or will I need to use -l php somehow?
Thank you for your patience with a newbie.
I tried pmd check -R rulesets/php/quickstart.xml -f text --dir MyProjectPhp and expected it existed as internal ruleset or a directory somewhere.

Is this what you are looking for? https://docs.pmd-code.org/latest/pmd_languages_php.html

sorta, after reading an answer I could understand that php is only supported as cpd as the table referenced makes clear, thank you

The list of languages supported by the latest version of PMD (7.2) is given in the project home page:

Currently, PMD supports Java, JavaScript, Salesforce.com Apex and Visualforce, Kotlin, Swift, Modelica, PLSQL, Apache Velocity, JSP, WSDL, Maven POM, HTML, XML and XSL. Scala is supported, but there are currently no Scala rules available.

As you can see, PHP is not one of them.
You may take a look at PHPMD instead, which is a tool inspired by PMD and dedicated to PHP.

Yes, PMD supports only CPD (Copy-Paste-Detection) for PHP, see https://docs.pmd-code.org/latest/pmd_languages_php.html

thank you so much, yes I could use the cpd module but did not know check was not supported, PHPMD seem to be what I was looking for, accepted your answer thanks so much :)
